# jQuery - How to bypass a global event

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

There is a global event on my site which fires on every ajax call.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    ShowLoader();
});
```

There are many ajax functionalities across the website and hence a global method.

And there is this new news feed feature on my site, where a user can click the button to see feed. This service is provided by a third party, who have asked me to place a script and add `btn-NewsFeed` class to the button, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="url to a third party javascript"></script>
   <a class="btn btn-NewsFeed">
      Get News Feed
   </a>
```

The anchor click makes an ajax call, but this method is in an external file which I cannot modify.

However, I can add another class & write a click event for this anchor tag on my site.

Is there a way, to just stop the global event for this anchor click and still not disturb its functionality.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The button is on my site

Comment: Are all click  event handled by the 3rd party script?

Comment: @Vince. No. All are handled in my site and there are many. Only this particular anchor click is handled by the 3rd party script.

Comment: You can add an additional event listener on that particular click and hide the loader immediately

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in your global eventhandler function, something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (event, xhr, settings) {
   if ($(event.target).hasClass('btn-Newsfeed')) { 
     return;
   }
   ShowLoader();
});
```

## edit

This won't work since this is not an `.on('click'), ...` handler where you have the element. So you have to do something different.

You can set `global` to false, then this method will not fire, as [per the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) (you need to scroll down to "Additional Notes":

> If `$.ajax()` or `$.ajaxSetup()` is called with the `global` option set to `false`, the `.ajaxStart()` method will not fire.

Edit: Further explanation necessary. [Read the documentation of jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/). Here you see the parameter `global` which is set to true by default. Set this one to false to not trigger `.ajaxStart()`

Comment: `event.target` is actually returning `#document` when I checked in the console.

Comment: I wrote this from the top of my head, maybe you need (like in the other answer) `event.target.activeElement` . Nevertheless the element should be in the event property, so if you output it to the console you should find it (and then reference it and check for classes, ID, whatever)

Comment: `event.target.activeElement` returns the `body` tag & its content,

Comment: check my edit, I was wrong with my first assumption

Comment: "is called with global set to false". could you please explain.

Comment: updated my answer to show you the point in the documentation where this is explained.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`event.target.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement) to find which element currently has focus and based on that check if that element also have the class `btn-NewsFeed`. If true, simply return from the `ajaxStart` method, so that `ShowLoader()` function in never called, else continue with it.

```js
$(document).ajaxStart(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  if ($(event.target.activeElement).hasClass("btn-NewsFeed")) return;
  ShowLoader();
});

function ShowLoader() {
  console.log('ShowLoader called!')
}

$('.btn-NewsFeed').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.clear();

  $.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", function(data) {
    console.log('Title: ', data.title)
  });
});
$('.btn-HomeFeed').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.clear();

  $.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2", function(data) {
    console.log('Title: ', data.title)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-HomeFeed" href="#">Get Home Feed</a><br>
<a class="btn btn-NewsFeed" href="#">Get News Feed</a>
```

Comment: `event.target.activeElement` returns the `body` tag & its content, when I checked in console.

Comment: `event.target` is returning `#document `

Comment: What does `event.currentTarget.activeElement` returns? Also, is this demo working for you?